# In YII2 How to run a particular queue job ID in controller?

Tags: php, yii2, queue

I used the yiisoft /yii2-queue  extension for queue
https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-queue
I want to fetch a particular job ID from the queue table and run that JOB ID.

Answer (score 0):

It's not natively supported. As a workaround, you could try utilizing an internal [`Command.actionExec()`](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-queue/blob/ab00a79323907710f44ff6c556662ee1a4e1cac0/src/cli/Command.php#L135C28-L135C28), with has the following doc block and signature:

```php
/**
 * Executes a job.
 * The command is internal, and used to isolate a job execution. Manual usage is not provided.
 *
 * @param string|null $id of a message
 * @param int $ttr time to reserve
 * @param int $attempt number
 * @param int $pid of a worker
 * @return int exit code
 * @internal It is used with isolate mode.
 */
public function actionExec($id, $ttr, $attempt, $pid)
```

So, try utilizing it in this format:

```bash
$ php yii queue/exec "id" "ttr" "attempt" "pid"
```

[`php` and `yii` should be known to shell or be paths to the executables.]

For an illustration how to use it in the code, look at the [Command.handleMessage()](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-queue/blob/ab00a79323907710f44ff6c556662ee1a4e1cac0/src/cli/Command.php#L163):

```php
$cmd = [
    $this->phpBinary,
    $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'],
    $this->uniqueId . '/exec',
    $id,
    $ttr,
    $attempt,
    $this->queue->getWorkerPid() ?: 0,
];

foreach ($this->getPassedOptions() as $name) {
    if (in_array($name, $this->options('exec'), true)) {
        $cmd[] = '--' . $name . '=' . $this->$name;
    }
}
if (!in_array('color', $this->getPassedOptions(), true)) {
    $cmd[] = '--color=' . $this->isColorEnabled();
}

$process = new Process($cmd, null, null, $message, $ttr);
```